# Sorting numbers in ascending order

Tags: c, arrays

I've written program to input numbers and print them in ascending order in C. I have tried, but it is not working properly.  Can anyone tell me how to do it the right way?

I have tried using sorting but it is not working in a proper way; how to do it?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int highest,temp=0; //decleartion
    int a[5];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]); //taking input
    }
    highest=a[0];
    for(i=1;i<5;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]<a[0])
        {
            temp=a[0];
            a[0]=a[i];
            a[i]=temp; //comparing
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",a[i]); //printing
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: have a read at the bubble sort technique and try implementing the code again :)

Comment: Determine the maximum element and repeat the process to determine the maximum for the remaining elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try this-

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    for (j = i + 1; j < n; ++j)
    {
        if (number[i] > number[j])
        {
            number[i] = number[i] + number[j];
            number[j] = number[i] - number[j];
            number[i] = number[i] - number[j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a very silly way of swapping two elements of an array.  It runs the risk of overflow completely unnecessarily, and incurs the cost of three arithmetic operations which will take up more space than one temporary variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works only for comparison of first two elements.

Try this -

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    for (j = i + 1; j < n; ++j)
    {
        if (number[i] > number[j])
        {
            temp =  number[i];
            number[i] = number[j];
            number[j] = temp;
          }
      }
  }
```